# How to stop AppleIDAuthAgent flooding the console log with messages about expired apple id

Tags: apple-id, macos, console

After upgrading to Mountain Lion I have noticed this message being flooded into my system console:

```
AppleIDAuthAgent[179]: SERVER Removing certificate for Apple ID "...@???.??" dsID="XXXXX" because it has expired or been revoked. (renewCertificateForAccount()/AppleIDAuthd.cpp #143) accountCheckDispatch
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to result from deprecated MobileMe and iDisk preference files laying around. [This post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19122650#19122650) at the Apple discussion forum may help you delete the relevant files:

```
~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.DotMacSync*.plist.lockfile
~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.idisk*.plist
~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.idisk*.plist.lockfile
~/Library/Preferences/MobileMeAccounts.plist
~/Library/Preferences/MobileMeAccounts.plist.lockfile
~/Library/Prefernces/ByHost/com.apple.coreservices.appleidauthenticationinfo*.plist
~/Library/Prefernces/ByHost/com.apple.coreservices.appleidauthenticationinfo*.plist.lockfile
```

Don't forget to close relevant applications (like Mail or Messages) before the deletion; it also might be a good idea to at least log out and in again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove and add again the apple ID attached to your user account (System Preferences > Users & Groups).